# Relationship between lunges (dumbbells) and squat

Tags: workout-routines, workout, squats, hypertrophy, progress

Let's imagine that my 5RM in the squat is 85kg because I'm just starting out. So I can only contract physiologically slowly, and to avoid injuries I stretch slowly. The last rep is quite well done, but shaking for example. 5RM. 85kg.

Does the squat allow to estimate the 5WD at the barbell lunges? If so, it would allow me to find the ideal workload for 80%5RM for example for lunges. This would be a simple way to plan my progress through the lunges.

Comment: I don't have an answer for that, but reading through your questions is painful. Stop worrying about useless shit like time under tension, 80%5RM or push/pull/leg split. It obviously doesn't get you anywhere. Grab a copy of an established beginner full body routine like Starting Strength, 5x5, Greyskull LP and start lifting.
You don't 'plan' progress at the stage you're at. Each workout you lift heavier weights than in the workout before. Until you fail to do so. Then you deload for that excercise. That should keep you busy for the next year or so.

Comment: I deload to what previous weight?

Comment: 90% of the weight that you failed to do the prescribed amount of reps. Most beginner routines that stood the test of time are a variation of Rippetoes' Starting Strength protocol. Here's a link to my personal favourite routine: https://thefitness.wiki/routines/r-fitness-basic-beginner-routine/ . Simple and effective.

Comment: Estimate? yes, i, d guess a couple of kg less than half your squat. but why do you need to know that? Just try with a low weight until you've learned the movement and go from there. If I told you 50% of beginners (you haven't included your height, weight, age... but don't bother) can lift 35 kg and it turns out you can't, what do you do then? Better start low

Comment: @Raditz_35 looking for an equality/equation.

Comment: Please understand that what you are asking is nonsense. You can't pick of with lunges where you've left with squats. Lunges are a new movement you have to learn first. You will drastically improve how much you can lift within your first couple training sessions. You don't have a meaningful 80% 5rm if you've never done the movement

Answer (score 1):

> Does the squat allow to estimate the 5WD at the barbell lunges?

No. It does not. Having a higher squat may allow you to have a higher lunge just by the fact that it makes you stronger. However, they are fundamentally different movements and as such, there is no set formula where you can guess what weight your lunge should be.

The strategy to find the appropriate weight is simple. Start with a weight that you can easily handle without issue. Do a set for the rep range you are targeting. Gauge how easy it was. Increase the weight slightly higher and do another set. After two or three sets, you'll find a weight where it actually is a struggle. Stick with that continuing forward.

Assistance exercises typically aren't used in the 5 rep range as it is. They are meant to correct imbalances (for example if one leg is much stronger than the other). As such, it would be better to do them at a lower weight but higher volume compared to compound lifts like squat.